# Get parameter from android method

Tags: java, android, uri

I have this method to scan file media after taking a shot with my app:

```
public static void refreshMedia() {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[] { photo.toString() }, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);             
            }
        });
    }
```

Now i need to retrive the uri that is a parameter of this method.. how can i do it? Because i need use the uri in another class..

Answer (score 1):

```
private static Uri mUri; // private variable in your class
....
public static void refreshMedia() {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
            new String[] { photo.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            mUri = uri; //<--Add this line to assign uri to mUri
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);             
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

Before Starting new intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
i.putExtra("MY_Uri", mUri);
```

in other class:

```
String mUri; //private variable
```

inside `onCreate()`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras == null) {
    mUri= null;
} else {
    mUri= extras.getString("MY_Uri");
}
```

Comment: No, Variable must be static. Else `mUri` will reset to default value if class got instantiate

Comment: ok seems perfect. but if i try to retrive the uri to open the picture from app from another class like: `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(Utils.mUri.toString())));` the app crashes with a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

create a `static` variable in class level with getter and setter.

```
private static Uri uri;
```

Then store `uri` to get this value from some where else.

```
public static void refreshMedia() {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
            new String[] { photo.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    YourClassName.uri=uri; // store uri
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
}
```